# Tag Proposition: media-comparison

Tags: discussion, tags

For questions like these two:

- [How much difference is there between Chronicles of the Going Home Club anime and manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28786/1587)
- [Why is the Black Jack anime and manga so different?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/31605/1587)

I feel a tag called [media-difference](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media-difference) could be added, used for when one is asking about difference between anime/manga/light novel adaptations. i.e., how much of a manga has a anime adapted or asking about content difference between a manga and light novel (like with *From the New World*).

While I can just make this tag myself, I was hoping to check whether making this tag would be of any benefit beyond just me thinking it would be good to have it in the mix.

Comment: I don't believe such a meta tag is useful to have. I mean, what function do you believe such a tag would have on it's own, as compared to it existing in tandem with a series tag? Meta tags should be able to able to be used on their own w/o another tag. [tag:anime-production] is a good example of this. Comparing differences between media with the same title should fall under the series title tag itself. If it's a question specific to the anime, then why not use the [tag:anime-production] tag along with it?

Comment: Unrelated: Any idea what's up with spelling "manga" in camelcase? I've that happen sometimes around here, and am not sure where it comes from...

Comment: @JNat it's probably just a odd stylistic choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I personally see any value in a new tag; even though you're talking about two different forms of media, you're still talking about the same series.

For example, take [How much does the Chuunibyou anime differ from the light novels?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3559/102).  The series still being referred to is still [chuunibyou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chuunibyou), and even though the anime and the manga are definitely not the same thing, the question is asking what the differences in adaptation are.

I don't really see users being experts or being able to contribute a lot of useful knowledge on adaptation differences *in general*, but I do see them being able to contribute adaptation differences *on a specific work*.