# 2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4067/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

Due to the submission count, we have selected all provided questions as well as our back up questions for a total of 10 questions.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/b71172bc-35f8-45e0-af6d-92b94e14811f/view-source).Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

[**Makoto's answers**](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4079/102)

[**Dimitri MX's answers**](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4080/1458)

---

> 1. How much do you know about the following series: *Naruto*, *One Piece*, *Fairy Tail*, *Bleach*, *Dragon Ball*?
> 2. What are, in your opinion, the current issues our StackExchange is facing and how do you plan to address them if you were elected as a moderator?
> 3. One thing I have noticed is that most of our Mod Team do not appear in the main Chat Room, to the point that most can't being be @ pinged. While Chat is optional it does provide a platform to contact Mods and discuss policies/decisions as opposed to using custom flags or posting on Meta and it does make a Mod more approachable. As a Mod would you become more active/participate in Chat? if not how would you open yourself up to being contacted outside of flagging and Meta Posts?
> 4. We have [a number of community events](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2682/1587) from annual events like [Conspiracy Santa](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2684/1587) to one off events like [EU A&M Meet up](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2692/1587). Are there any other Events you would like to see occur to help bolster community cohesion, attract more users to the site and/or increase activity and participation on the site? Apart from the idea of *events*, are there any other ways you would encourage the community to grow and collaborate?
> 5. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 6. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 7. What example can you point to, either here or on another site in the network, that is most indicative of your moderation style? How would you adapt it to fit for this site?
> 8. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 9):

> 1. How much do you know about the following series: *Naruto*, *One Piece*, *Fairy Tail*, *Bleach*, *Dragon Ball*?

Of the franchises listed:

- I've watched nearly the entirety of Naruto and half of *Shippuden*, but have read the entire manga.
- I've not pleasently experienced One Piece; the only versions I saw were the 4Kids dub way back when.
- I've not watched or read Fairy Tail, but I am keen to look into it.
- I'm *very* well versed in Bleach.  Of the "big three", this was the one I faithfully stuck with to completion.
- My knowledge of Dragon Ball ends at around Z, but I know bits and pieces of the other series.

I would counter, however, that regardless of my knowledge levels of these series, it's still prudent for me to do the research on them *anyway* and look into what they're all about.  I don't personally feel that having an *encyclopedic* level of knowledge on these series is vital, but knowing what to look for in a high quality question *is*.

In that vein, there are heuristics I use to determine a good question even if I don't have experience with the series:

- Can it realistically occur in the canon?  ([Example.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/40710/102))
- Does the question cite specific episodes or major plot points?  ([Example.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/17009/102))
- Is the question something that can be answered as a fan (myself), or by someone with *some* insight into the industry? ([Example.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/38846/102))

As this is a heuristic it is subject to flaws, but by and large I feel that I have a good eye for good questions.

> 2. What are, in your opinion, the current issues our StackExchange is facing and how do you plan to address them if you were elected as a moderator?

We have a bit of an issue with diversity of questions.  As alluded to in an earlier question, we've got a serious focus on the major franchises (Naruto, One Piece, Bleach, Fairy Tail, etc.), but not as much focus on the smaller or newer ones.  There are two issues at play here:  reach and personal watching habits.

The former is well out of our control; we can't dictate (very well, anyway) which series become the next Big Thing in Japan, so we would have to divert our attention to the latter.  This means that events like group watching sessions or chat discussions around new series would  be beneficial, as it'd get a guy like myself (who's very stuck in his "not interested in cute girls doing cute things series but OMG *New Game* does programming and I do too!  Wow!!"-ways) interested in other series.

That's a lot harder since I personally haven't been to any of those events held by us here - scheduling conflicts, mostly - and I don't know what measure of success they have.  But having more of these events more often and geared towards a wider diversity of genres would be beneficial.  Who knows; *maybe* doing that I'll actually watch *Yuri on Ice* or *Free*.  *Maybe.*

> 3. One thing I have noticed is that most of our Mod Team do not appear in the main Chat Room, to the point that most can't being be @ pinged. While Chat is optional it does provide a platform to contact Mods and discuss policies/decisions as opposed to using custom flags or posting on Meta and it does make a Mod more approachable. As a Mod would you become more active/participate in Chat? if not how would you open yourself up to being contacted outside of flagging and Meta Posts?

The way my schedule and routine are structured prevent me from going to chat, but I am prepared to make adjustments which would mean I do go into chat.  I don't mind being reached for when needed, but I'd like to set up a system that works for me too.  Might fiddle with some notifications APIs to make it more convenient.

> 4. We have [a number of community events](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2682/1587) from annual events like [Conspiracy Santa](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2684/1587) to one off events like [EU A&M Meet up](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2692/1587). Are there any other Events you would like to see occur to help bolster community cohesion, attract more users to the site and/or increase activity and participation on the site? Apart from the idea of *events*, are there any other ways you would encourage the community to grow and collaborate?

This is a lot tougher as we really look to find where we fit in the vast and broad community of Anime and Manga discussion places.  We've got our share of growing pains with what is and isn't acceptable on our site - notably the identification question issue among others - but that may stem from a deeper identity crisis.  We're quite happy and content with being what we are, which is a repository of knowledge for Anime and Manga, but to others, that seems to conflate to "forum", and we're simply not that.  An emphasis on growth would require clear and readily visible expectations to others as to what we're looking for.

I quite liked senshin's [past efforts](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/april-2015-bounties-for-tags-sports-anime-2005-present) to facilitate activity and encourage new content here, but ultimately that also meant that we'd have to *want* to contribute to that.  I would love an opportunity to bring something like that back, but instead of tying it to a theme or anything like that, I'd rather want to see some deeply insightful questions from other anime that are harder to answer.  I don't have the rep to facilitate something like that for very long, but I'd still like to see it.

> 5. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Pull 'em aside and have a chat.  I'd want to see what's really going on behind those flags and figure out if it's a deeper issue than two users having a disagreement of some sort.

> 6. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Moderators should act as a quorum, and we should respect the decisions of fellow moderators.  That said, I'd take them aside and ask them why they felt why they took the action they did.  Then I'd present my side and give reasons why I feel their actions weren't right.  I'm looking for consensus in the decision made, and possibly I would also learn a bit more into how they feel moderation is and should be done around here.

> 7. What example can you point to, either here or on another site in the network, that is most indicative of your moderation style? How would you adapt it to fit for this site?

Of the posts on A&M:

- [I'm pretty happy with this one](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3893/102); it communicated my express opinion on what value a series tag holds here, since "the universe" is much broader in scope than "this instance", and "the universe" may not even have an equivalent "instance".  (I did notice that it was re-added afterwards, so I went back and corrected that.)
- [This one is pretty good too.](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2810/102)  I feel that a new tag for that subject would've been too broad and I communicated that clearly and respectfully.

Of the posts elsewhere:

I'm quite (in)famous on Stack Overflow nowadays - feel encouraged to [look at my answers for more details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto?tab=answers), but of the posts here, I feel like these capture an applicable style for A&M best:

- [What we do with non-native English speakers' posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291179/1079354); if it can be edited into shape, we should edit it into shape.
- [Understanding the scope of an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302624/1079354), and how "Not an Answer"-answers can be identified.
- [Encouraging users to provide answers even if they're not innately familiar with the subject matter.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351688/1079354)  I feel like *this* is the thing we should be promoting a *lot* here, since not everyone really knows every anime.
- [Editing advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339127/1079354); domain knowledge is not required to know that "I" should be capitalized.
- [Encouraging the long-form answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351433/1079354); we're small (and I allude to as much in another answer in that post), and we don't draw lots of attention to long-form answers, but that doesn't mean we should *stop* doing them.

> 8. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

As a high-rep user on another site, I've come to see moderators as folks that can handle the things that I can't handle.  That is, they handle the more intangible issues of the community, such as voting rings, users needing a timeout (potentially), and various parts of the community that no other user is privy to, such as warnings and suspensions, and even deleting comments.  Effectively, they clean up the mess that others can't *quite* clean up.  As we've still got beta-level privileges, my reputation here is near equivalent to that of a high-rep moderator-user on a fully-graduated site, so this means that there are a decent number of users here who still contribute to cleaning things up.  Moderators are there to help when the community can't *quite* accomplish it on their own, which I feel is a good role.

> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

In the best cases, it reflects well on the community for having placed their confidence in my history.  In the worst case, it highlights that I, too, am human, and make human mistakes.

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

This is hard to quantify on a smaller site, but the main issue(s) we would potentially have around here is content that can't be removed in a timely enough fashion, such as content which goes against the ToS of the site.  Also, moderators are the only kind of user who can remove comments, and removing offensive comments timely is something only a moderator can help with.

Comment: "An emphasis on growth would require clear and readily visible expectations to others as to what we're looking for." I actually think that's the Catch 22 we've been stuck in as a site for a while now. Like all SE sites, we are very clear and rigid about our expectations. (Visibility, eh. It's all out there, if you're looking for it.) But that's not what most anime fans online seem to expect or want out of a community, contrary to programmers or mathematicians or even sci-fi and fantasy fans, so we have a hard time growing.

Comment: It doesn't help that anime fans tend to be young and non-native English speakers. A lot of them bristle under too many restrictions, even if you can get them to understand those restrictions and why they exist.

Comment: @Torisuda: Yeah, I tend to agree with this.  As I was typing this answer up, it too occurred to me that this was the trap that we've fallen into.  We're a strange hodgepodge of community-but-not-interested-in-discussions-outside-of-chat which rubs some the wrong way.  It's like I was saying on the nomination page; regardless of how this shakes out, we've gotta start doing something to address this.  I've got a few ideas, but we'll need time and more cooperation from the people we already have to really make it work well.

Answer (score 7):

### Dimitri-MX

> 1. How much do you know about the following series: *Naruto*, *One Piece*, *Fairy Tail*, *Bleach*, *Dragon Ball*?

Fairly knowledgeable. In case of Naruto and Bleach I have read the whole manga series, and have it physically available at home for review.
As for Fairy Tail, One Piece and Dragonball I follow the releases as they come. So consider me up to date.

> 2. What are, in your opinion, the current issues our StackExchange is facing and how do you plan to address them if you were elected as a moderator?

There seems to be little variety in questions, and I think the very first question answered reflects that quite clearly.
This has been a thing for as long as I have been an active member, and I think this mainly caused by the type of people the community attracts. Which often just 'want to know/need help' with finding an serie/song
Figuring out a way to attract more dedicated fans would be my approach on fixing this particular issue.

> 3. One thing I have noticed is that most of our Mod Team do not appear in the main Chat Room, to the point that most can't being be @ pinged. While Chat is optional it does provide a platform to contact Mods and discuss policies/decisions as opposed to using custom flags or posting on Meta and it does make a Mod more approachable. As a Mod would you become more active/participate in Chat? if not how would you open yourself up to being contacted outside of flagging and Meta Posts?

Personally, I am also not an active chat user on A&M. However, when becoming a Mod I will attempt to be so more. 
Besides that I actually am available on a lot of other chat services such as skype and discord, As I prefer to work with desktop clients for chatting.
These clients also offer mobile support, which makes me available nearly 24/7 on these mediums, and always up for a chat.

> 4. We have [a number of community events](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2682/1587) from annual events like [Conspiracy Santa](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2684/1587) to one off events like [EU A&M Meet up](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2692/1587). Are there any other Events you would like to see occur to help bolster community cohesion, attract more users to the site and/or increase activity and participation on the site? Apart from the idea of *events*, are there any other ways you would encourage the community to grow and collaborate?

I have been part of some of these events and would extend a helping hand if community members decide to create new events. However, I wouldn't currently have any suggestions for said events.

> 5. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Would be dependant on the type of flags, however assuming that it's just to chatty/ extended discussions 
would redirect the users to chat, to continue their discussion there instead as comments are not for extended discussions, and point this fact out to them.

> 6. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Discuss it with the the said mod. See if you can reach some sort of mutual consensus, or if it escalates beyond that, included other moderators or some cases the community it self as well.

> 7. What example can you point to, either here or on another site in the network, that is most indicative of your moderation style? How would you adapt it to fit for this site?

I guess I would point out https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2660/1458 , moderation can be hard, especially considering borderline materials. 
So by helping define limits, both as a moderator assisted by the members of the community we can keep a nice and safe place.

And if people need clarifications, help, or an explanation. https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2655/1458 Ill give it to them

> 8. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

They mediate, maintain, answer and respond to the community, there where the user driven moderation is insufficient.

> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

Not that different. People will see that they can reach out to me if they need help or have questions. Besides that, I am still a community member.

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Yes, I think it make it easier for people to reach out to me if they need anything.

Comment: "Figuring out a way to attract more dedicated fans would be my approach on fixing this particular issue." We seem to have plenty of dedicated fans of the five series mentioned in the first question, so to produce a change would require attracting dedicated fans of the wider medium. I'm curious if you have any concrete ideas to accomplish this. I see good writing about anime on personal blogs, but none of those people seem interested in joining a community, and I've come to believe after participating on Literature that SE just isn't well structured for certain kinds of writing about media.

Comment: @Torisuda As I feel my answer would very roughly exceed the character limit ill try to condense it a bit, so sorry if anything is lost in this process. There is a huge difference between Q&A style, and blog style of answering questions. Where blogging allows for a far wider view. Where as on A&M you will have to condense data, which would be less attractive to said people. So like you mentioned, it's not structured for writing about media. However, to attract said people to A&M, would could find a common ground for them where they can express themselves both ways without much additional effort

Comment: The key challenge being, the common ground. Which could be, a summarization of their answer, and more publicity/readers of their publications. Without losing data in the process on the answer, but also attracting people to read on in the blog. However, if it where that easy, it would probably happen a lot more than it does already. So I guess finding a more pro-active way to do so would bring the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on the issue. I guess what I was really getting at is that a lot of the most interesting questions about media in general, including anime and manga, are questions that you wouldn't think to ask unless you were already working on an answer, and don't gain anything from the rigid question / response format of an SE site. I think you're right that finding a way for people who are interested in these topics to be able to write about them in some form within the restrictions of SE could be a way forward.